# Maximum number of filters for Twitter Streaming API

Tags: streaming, twitter

What is the maximum number of filters one can track with the Twitter Streaming API?

I'm under the impression that the limit is based more upon the rate at which tweets are streaming to your connection, however, I can't imagine they allow a ton of filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track up to 400 single words, or 5,000 users. The limit beyond that is a max of 1% of the total flow of all tweets.